# Gas issue on sendRawTransaction on the rinkeby network

Tags: ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum

I'm facing a gas issue on rinkeby network on `sendRawTransaction`.

Tested with various gas value to experiment and getting either insufficient funds for gas * price + value or exceeds block gas limit.

Some more info:
Gas Estimate: 32872
Balance: 1100000 Gwei
gas: 87200

Any suggestions or anybody faced similar issue?

My code here: https://gist.github.com/anistark/2daf9295a4d5a03cb405ff5a47924b32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new private key is unrelated to the original address. And it will have zero balance unless funded explicitely.

Solution: Extract the same private key instead.